# BeautifulSoup Extracting Text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to rewrite a script I already did, but I deleted it accidentally.  I want to use time.gov as a reference to what time it is and then set the system time of the machine using the time extracted from time.gov using BeautifulSoup.  I can't figure out how to isolate the changing time from time.gov in my code.

I've already tried using bs4 to get the div and class that has the changing time in it by using Chrome's inspect function.

Here is what i have so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.time.gov/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
time = soup.find(attrs={'class':'lzswftext'})
print (time.string)
```

The expected result is simply the time in plaintext.  Afterwards, I'll use python to convert the time to military/24 hour time then place that into the time command to set the system time.  I'll use task scheduler to mimic setting NTP time on a schedule.  I'm doing this because I constantly am getting machines that can't figure out NTP network time when set to auto so I'm making them web requests on an interval instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get because it rendered by javascript and but you can get the time from from other URL

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime

url = "https://nist.time.gov/widget/actualtime.cgi"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
timestamp = soup.find('timestamp').get('time')
# in microseconds
print(timestamp)

# convert to human readable
# need to divide by million or error "year is out of range"
timestamp = int(timestamp) / 1e6
print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))
# or
print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

# est time
import pytz
tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz)
print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'))
```

Comment: Awesome, but how can I convert it to EST time zone.  My computer now says it is five hours forward than it actually is.

Comment: Thanks @ewwink for the work.  I parsed out the date and time strings and put them into windows commands date and time, and it worked perfectly.  now i'll just run it as an admin and schedule it in task scheduler to keep my network time.  Thanks again